# libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: software-installation, cmake

I'm trying to install [this](https://github.com/yuasatakayuki/RubyFits#install) library for Ruby so I can work with FITS files, but during `brew install sfitsio` I encounter this error:

```
Last 15 lines from /home/dachsroot/.cache/Homebrew/Logs/sllib/02.cmake:
2017-10-21 12:36:01 -0300

cmake
.
-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG
-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/dachsroot/.linuxbrew/Cellar/sllib/1.4.2e
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
-DCMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK=LAST
-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON
-Wno-dev

cmake: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've tried to find a solution, but all I find are solutions that say I have to install `libstdc++6`, but I already that package installed.

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libstdc++6 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

The entire `02.cmake` file is [here](https://pastebin.com/gBs9Qcyy).

What can I do?

Comment: Do you have `g++` installed?

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes, version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)